# Standardization for interaction with on-line software invoicing

Tags: protocols, standards, saas

I am writing a software which sells certain service to it's user. I am aware of hundreds of different invoicing tools around - Freshbooks, Invocie machine, Xero, SortMyBooks are just to name a few. They all have an API but integrating with each is so much work.

Is there any **protocol or indicative to create a universal data exchange protocol**, which would allow user to specify invoicing system of their choice on my software and have two product communicate seamlessly without prior knowledge of each-other existence?

---

Of course this issue goes beyond invoicing. How to connect time reporting tool with thousand of project-tracking portals? How to exchange task between Getflow and Taskify?

p.s. I'm not asking on "[Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)" because it's clearly more focused on the user-side of web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several standard EDI formats for invoicing, including (but not limited to) EDIFACT's [INVOIC](http://www.stylusstudio.com/edifact/D95B/INVOIC.htm) message, ANSI X12's 810 message, as well as more proprietary XML formats such as VISA's